# Creating zero-byte file for every file and appending an extension to the end

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want this to recurse every directory and create a zero-byte file for every file using the same name as the file with the extension .xxx added.  I was thinking `New-Item` would be good to use here but I cant seem to get it working right.

Here is what I've tried with no success in PS version 2:

```
$drivesArray = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem' | select -Expand Root 
foreach ($drive in $drivesArray) {
  ls "$drive" | where {
    $_.FullName -notlike "${Env:WinDir}*" -and
    $_.FullName -notlike "${Env:ProgramFiles}*"
  } | ls -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -recurse | where {
    -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
    $_.Extension -notmatch '\.xxx|\.exe|\.html'
  } | New-Item -Path { $_.BaseName } -Name ($_.FullName+".xxx") -Type File -Force
}
```

This errors out with

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument "+xxx".

Comment: `"$($_.FullName).xxx"` I am sure there could be other improvements though. I don't know if this code will get you want you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap both the second `Get-ChildItem` (`ls`) and the `New-Item` in `ForEach-Object` statements. Also, do not pass `$_.Basename` as the path to `New-Item`. Do it either like this:

```
New-Item -Path ($_.FullName + '.xxx') -Type File -Force
```

or like this:

```
New-Item -Path $_.Directory -Name ($_.Name + '.xxx') -Type File -Force
```

Modified code:

```
foreach ($drive in $drivesArray) {
  Get-ChildItem $drive | Where-Object {
    $_.FullName -notlike "${Env:WinDir}*" -and
    $_.FullName -notlike "${Env:ProgramFiles}*"
  } | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  } | Where-Object {
    -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
    $_.Extension -notmatch '^\.(xxx|exe|html)$'
  } | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -Path ($_.FullName + '.xxx') -Type File -Force
  }
}
```

Comment: With this code I get a bunch of 'access denied' that appear to be mostly in the Windows\system folder.  Also, no zero-byte files are created.

New-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\..\MSFT_GroupResource.schema.mfl.xxx' is denied.

Comment: @shadw_it Sorry, my mistake. I forgot to add the path to the second `Get-ChildItem`. Fixed.